# values don't match in python groupby.apply

Tags: python, pandas

```
def _hit_rate(df):
    df['hit'] = 1
    return df['ca'].mean()

a = pd.DataFrame({'geo':['AP','AP','AP','SD','SD','SD'],'lower':[1.2,1.2,1.2,1.3,1.3,1.3],'ca':[1,1,1,2,2,2]})
print(a)

b = a.groupby(['geo']).apply(_hit_rate)
print(b)
```

I want to do some action in `_hit_rate()`, and than return the mean.
but if I did like that, the df's values will be wrong in `_hit_rate` function.
the `df[df['geo'='SD']['ca']` will equal to `df[df['geo'='AP']['ca']`, not itself value 2 but get the wrong 1.
I feel confused about this, please help me!

Comment: can you please describe in better details what is wrong? I cannot see the problem you face, getting 2 for SD and 1 for AP, that is what I expected. Maybe you have more code you haven't shown? Also it would be nice to tell us what is expected output and what is your actuall output, as I was not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You can go ahead and edit your question with required output. And to consider your problem here your function is calculating `mean` on `ca` after `groupby` execution as for `SD` mean for `ca` will be `(1+1+1)/3` that is `1` and for `AP` mean is `(2+2+2/3)` which is `2` so it is giving you the correct result. However community here can precisely help you on your problem if you provide the expected output what you want and currently what your problem is.

Comment: What does `df['hit'] = 1` do in your function? Right now it doesnt seem to have any use because you are just returning the mean of `df['ca']`.  Also, what is the expected output and what are you getting ? Could you explain what you are actually trying to do with the `.apply()`?